# Adding a shortcut for "Change Adapter Settings"

Tags: windows-7, networking, control-panel

Is it possible to create a desktop shortcut for "Change Adapter Settings" in windows 7?

I run virtual machines, that I need to enable/disable NICs frequently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a shortcut to network connections by following this:

1) Right click on a empty area on the desktop and click on 'New' and 'Shortcut'.

[image]

2) Enter this `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL ncpa.cpl` in the 'Type the location of the item' field as shown below
[image]

3) Now provide a name for your shortcut and click 'Finish' button. The shortcut should  be created on your desktop
[image]

Once this is done and you click it it should take you straight to 'Change adapter settings' screen.

Answer (score 25):

<sub>The accepted answer is nice and impressive, but its not the way Microsoft wants you to do it.</sub>

Instead you should drag & drop the icon in front of your Address Bar to your desktop.
This creates a shortcut and has already the correct icon and filename.

[image]

Btw. this method works with every `Control Panel` window

Comment: This is a far simpler method.

Comment: It is simpler but you cannot pin it to the taskbar without it getting absorbed into the control panel pinned application and requiring an additional click.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer by @Shivaranjan, an alternative way is `Win+R` and type `ncpa.cpl`:

[image]

Comment: Best answer!!!!